# How to increase the number of scrollable lines in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, rxvt, scrolling

Sometimes the output from one compilation is longer than the lines my `rxvt` terminal seems to hold; can I increase that? If so, how?

I know I can redirect output to files for later inspection, but I'm interested in this scenario of outputting in the terminal.

[This thread on ArchLinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=65437) seems to state there's no way to do that. Is it case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to start your `rxvt` using the `-sl`option: for example, `rxvt -sl 50000` to have a scrollback buffer of 50000 lines. The default is 1000 lines, at least on my Debian system.

Assuming that you are using a modern Unicode-compatible version of `rxvt`, the way to make this persistent would be to edit (or create) a file named `~/.Xresources` and add this line to it:

```
URxvt.saveLines: 50000
```

To make this setting effective, you'd need to logout & login again, or run this command in your current X session: `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

This is a common mechanism for configuring classic X applications, known as [X resources.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/x_resources)

The thread you linked refers to increasing the scroll-back buffer on the *text-mode virtual console* i.e. when the X11 GUI is not running, which requires kernel modification.

Comment: Oh, so I was misunderstanding _that_ post. Thanks!